# For loop accessing an array of objects with array's

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, if-statement

```
const bankAccounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 100.32,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 18456.57,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];

function getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let acc of bankAccounts) {
    if (acc.withdrawals) {
      newArr.push(acc.withdrawals)
    } else if (!acc.withdrawals) {
      newArr.push(0);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

I am getting access to the array objects. But how do I get into the objects with the array of withdrawals with varying amounts, add them all and print that in the blank array "newArr"? Do I need another for loop? My overall goal is to iterate through the objects check which ones pass that have withdrawals array. If they do not have a withdrawals array I pass 0. The objects that do have withdrawals I need to iterate through those and add them up and push the total of the withdrawal array into the "newArr".

Comment: `newArr.push(...acc.withdrawals)`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you would like the output to look like for the accounts given?

Comment: `newArr = withdrawals.slice(0)`

Comment: @NetByMatt I added some more text to clarify what I need a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a functional programming solution that uses map reduce:

```js
const bankAccounts = [ { id: 1, name: "Susan", balance: 100.32, deposits: [150, 30, 221], withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120], }, { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] }, { id: 3, name: "Joshua", balance: 18456.57, deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57], withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500], }, { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 }, { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] }, ];

function getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts) {
  return bankAccounts.map(obj => {
    return obj.withdrawals ? obj.withdrawals.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0) : 0;
  });
}

console.log(getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts));
```

Output:

```
[
  300.68,
  0,
  5900,
  0,
  100
]
```

Docs:

- Intro to map reduce: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d
- `.map()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
- `.reduce()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reduce

Here is an enhanced version where you pass the `deposits` or `withdrawls` key into the function:

```js
const bankAccounts = [ { id: 1, name: "Susan", balance: 100.32, deposits: [150, 30, 221], withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120], }, { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] }, { id: 3, name: "Joshua", balance: 18456.57, deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57], withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500], }, { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 }, { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] }, ];

function getSums(bankAccounts, key) {
  return bankAccounts.map(obj => {
    return obj[key] ? obj[key].reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0) : 0;
  });
}

console.log({
  deposits: getSums(bankAccounts, 'deposits'),
  withdrawals: getSums(bankAccounts, 'withdrawals'),
});
```

Output:

```
{
  "deposits": [
    401,
    1100,
    24456.57,
    0,
    118
  ],
  "withdrawals": [
    300.68,
    0,
    5900,
    0,
    100
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** Based on request to use only for loops:

```js
const bankAccounts = [ { id: 1, name: "Susan", balance: 100.32, deposits: [150, 30, 221], withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120], }, { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] }, { id: 3, name: "Joshua", balance: 18456.57, deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57], withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500], }, { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 }, { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] }, ];

function getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts) {
  let result = [];
  for (let obj of bankAccounts) {
    let sum = 0;
    if(obj.withdrawals) {
      for (num of obj.withdrawals) {
        sum += num;
      }
    }
    result.push(sum);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts));
```

Comment: can only use for loops

Comment: @OldsoulPhil: What is the reason to only use for loops?

Comment: trying to teach younger brother some things and I don't know to much about code. I know more than him, but not a lot.

Comment: @OldsoulPhil: Gotcha. See UPDATE 1

Comment: Thank you. Me and my brother appreciate you. I can help him better with his homework now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but if u have to sum ALL of the withdrawals you should do it in this way:

```js
const bankAccounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 100.32,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 18456.57,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];

function getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let acc of bankAccounts) {
    if (!!acc.withdrawals) {
    acc.withdrawals.forEach(withdrawal => newArr.push(withdrawal))
    }
  }
  return newArr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0);
}

console.log(getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts))
```

Otherwise if you have to sum the withdrawals of the single object you have to use this code:

```js
const bankAccounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 100.32,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 18456.57,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];

function getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let acc of bankAccounts) {
    if (!!acc.withdrawals) {
        newArr.push(acc.withdrawals.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0))
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(getAllWithdrawals(bankAccounts))
```

Comment: can only use for loops